# Combine multiple rows from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables;

**user** table

```
   id     first_name     last_name     country 
   2      John           Doe           USA
   3      Jimmy          Biglips       FRA
```

**user_meta** (metadata) table

```
user_id   meta_key       meta_value
   2      phone          3333
   2      rating         Good
   3      phone          7777
   3      rating         Bad
```

**country** table

```
country_id     country     country_fullname
    1          USA         United States of America
    2          FRA         France
```

I need to query by "rating" (e.g. "**good**") and return the result set as;

```
id  first_name    last_name     phone     rating    country     country_fullname 
2   John          Doe           33333     Good      USA         United States of America
```

Because the **user_meta** table has multiple rows that corresponds to a member in the **user** table, I was having trouble returning a combined set of values in one row.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just combine them in a `JOIN`. The `LEFT JOIN`s are there to allow for the row to show up even if the user has no phone/rating available;

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, p.meta_value phone, r.meta_value rating,
       u.country, c.country_fullname
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_meta p ON u.id=p.user_id AND p.meta_key='phone'
LEFT JOIN user_meta r ON u.id=r.user_id AND r.meta_key='rating'
JOIN country c ON u.country=c.country;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7175a/4).

Comment: Thanks for your help, consequently, I had to use INNER JOINs as opposed to LEFT JOINs. Otherwise I was receiving an empty result set. Could be an environment issue as I am passing this statement, in a slightly more complex form via a WordPress SQL statement i.e. `$wpdb->get_results( SQL );`. None the less, I've reached a reasonable outcome. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.first_name,
       u.last_name,
       MIN(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'phone' THEN meta_value END) phone,
       MIN(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'rating' THEN meta_value END) rating,
       u.country,
       c.country_fullname
  FROM user u LEFT JOIN user_meta m 
    ON u.id = m.user_id LEFT JOIN country c
    ON u.country = c.country
 GROUP BY u.id
```

Output:

```
| ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | PHONE | RATING | COUNTRY |         COUNTRY_FULLNAME |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |       John |       Doe |  3333 |   Good |     USA | United States of America |
|  3 |      Jimmy |   Biglips |  7777 |    Bad |     FRA |                   France |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f1ca6/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @peterm. I couldn't get this to work precisely as I wanted in my environment (see above comment) however the fiddle works no problem and this was much easier on the eye to read. +1 Thanks again.